# sumo Error: Vehicle '0' has no valid route. No connection between edges 'gneE17' and 'gneE20'

Tags: routes, traffic, sumo

I have been working with Netedit for some times now. But when I perform the simulation on sumo gui all I get everytime is *Error: Vehicle '0' has no valid route. No connection between edges 'gneE17' and 'gneE20'. Loading of net-file failed. Quitting (on error)* .

Please note here that *gneE17* is the ID for the beginning of the route. Also, below find the part code for the traffic data.

```
    <routes>
    <vType id="type1" accel="3" decel="1.5" sigma="0.5" length="5" maxspeed="70"/>
    <route id="route0" color="1,1,0" edges="gneE17 gneE20 -gneE18 gneE21 "/>
    </routes>

    <flow id="type1" color="1,1,0" begin="0" end="3600" VehsPerhour="200">
    <route edges="gneE17 gneE20 -gneE18 gneE21"/>
    </flow>
```

Comment: Did you check the network whether the edges are really connected?

Comment: you can share your network or at least connections file if exists so others can take a look at it as well.